# Are Chrome bookmarks automatically backed up?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, sync

I finally arranged my bookmarks in Chrome 33, inside bookmarks toolbar etc. Do I need to create a backup to save this arrangement (and How) OR it is automatically saved on Google server, inside my account?

In case of re-installing Windows or Chrome I want to load saved bookmarks settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Chrome has been setup to synchronize with your Google Account, then you bookmarks will also be synchronized. All you will have to do after reinstall (or on different computer) is to signing to same google account with chrome.

You can check the status of current Chrome Sync here: https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync

Answer (score 1):

Chrome bookmarks are not automatically backed up. There is the aforementioned option to sync bookmarks, but that's not the same thing as a backup. If you should accidentally delete a bookmark, for example, that same deletion would be synced immediately, so the sync isn't a good option for backup recovery.